# RabbitMQ return ack to requester

Tags: javascript, node.js, queue, rabbitmq

I have a service which gets http requests, and pass the request data to another service. This another service publishes messages to queue, and when the queue is pulled by the queue consumer, I want to return ack, and send it back to the requested server, in order to send it to another processing step (not by a queue). Do I need to have another queue in order to track the processed messages and consume it in the request server?

Wanted:
Server1->queue1->server1(queue1 result) - >queue2...

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Not necessarily, but I think it would require another explicit communication channel.

What is the nature of the work? What is the throughput? What is the performance profile? Will it be steady? bursty?

I could imagine:

**queue based ack**

-(http)> Service1 -> Another service -(messagequeue)> consumer

consumer -(messagequeue)> Service1

This should allow for async processing, service 1 would also be a consumer and would be waiting for ACK messages

**HTTP Based ack**

Instead of having your consumer ack by putting messages on a message queue it could ping service1 directly.

---

I def prefer option one, because it has all the benefits of a async message passing architecture:

- consumer and service 1 decoupled
- async processing

Comment: Hi  :)  i need it like that:  (http)->server1->server2->queue1->server2->queue2->server2->queue3 etc..